# Foundation 6.4 JavaScript within project not working, but external JS does

Tags: javascript, webpack, zurb-foundation, plyr.js

I am losing my mind with javascript in Foundation 6.4. I have no idea what's going on with this Webpack thing. It seems like some libraries/plugins work and some do not. My latest issue is with plyr (https://plyr.io/). I do not understand why TweenMax works 100% fine and plyr.js does not. What am I doing wrong?

This is the error I get..

`app.js:23026 Uncaught ReferenceError: plyr is not defined`

This is what my `app.js` looks like..

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import whatInput from 'what-input';


window.$ = $;
window.jQuery = $;


require('./TweenMax.js');
require('./plyr.js');


//import Foundation from 'foundation-sites';
// If you want to pick and choose which modules to include, comment out the above and uncomment
// the line below
import './lib/foundation-explicit-pieces';

$(document).foundation().ready(function(){

    TweenMax.set(".logo-center", {transformOrigin:"50% 50%"});

    var blast = plyr.setup('#blast', {
        hideControls: true,
        clickToPlay: false,
        controls: []
    }); 
});
```

I also have the path to plyr.js in my config.yml file:

```
# Your project's server will run on localhost:xxxx at this port
PORT: 8000

# Autoprefixer will make sure your CSS works with these browsers
COMPATIBILITY:
  - "last 2 versions"
  - "ie >= 10"
  - "ios >= 9"

# UnCSS will use these settings
UNCSS_OPTIONS:
  html:
    - "src/**/*.html"
  ignore:
    - !!js/regexp .foundation-mq
    - !!js/regexp ^\.is-.*

# Gulp will reference these paths when it copies files
PATHS:
  # Path to dist folder
  dist: "dist"  
  # Paths to static assets that aren't images, CSS, or JavaScript
  assets:
    - "src/assets/**/*"
    - "!src/assets/{img,js,scss}/**/*"
  # Paths to Sass libraries, which can then be loaded with @import
  sass:
    - "node_modules/foundation-sites/scss"
    - "node_modules/motion-ui/src"
  # Paths to JavaScript entry points for webpack to bundle modules
  entries:
    - "src/assets/js/app.js"
    - "src/assets/js/plyr.js"
    - "src/assets/js/TweenMax.js"
```

Comment: Can you provide the link of your app or the js?

Comment: Providing any accessible link to you project could really help solve your problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you started your Foundation project from [ZURB template](https://github.com/zurb/foundation-zurb-template). It uses a **Gulpfile** (`gulpfile.babel.js`) for JavaScript module bundling with Webpack.

Inside this script there is a [Webpack configuration](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/) like below:

```
let webpackConfig = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /.js$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader'
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Webpack config can define, in the module section, some rules for modules (configure loaders, parser options, etc.).
In particular *loaders* enable webpack to process files and bundle them (or do other Webpack tasks).

So the specific configuration in `gulpfile.babel.js` tells to Webpack to use [babel-loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/babel-loader/) for all files in /src folder with *js* extension.
However as explained in [Webpack - Shimming](https://webpack.js.org/guides/shimming/) some modules/libraries may expect global dependencies (e.g. $ for jQuery) or create globals which need to be exported.

To support these libraries, like [Plyr](https://github.com/sampotts/plyr), you can use [expose-loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/expose-loader/).
So add a module rule to Webpack config inside 
`gulpfile.babel.js`, pointing to [expose-loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/expose-loader/) for `plyr.js`:

```
let webpackConfig = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /plyr.js/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'expose-loader',
            options: 'plyr'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /.js$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader'
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

No other changes are needed to your project files (config.yml, app.js).

This way you should access `plyr` as global variable like in your `app.js`:

```
var blast = plyr.setup('#blast', {
    hideControls: true,
    clickToPlay: false,
    controls: []
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You might need to use something like [expose-loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/expose-loader/) so that `plyr` is available globally on `window`. [Here's more info](https://brian.olore.net/wp/2017/06/journey-to-webpack-2/) on how we used expose-loader in our project.

Answer (score 1):

Without the actual project code, it is rather difficult to figure out what went wrong. But here's my take on the situation.

First off, why are you import plyr from a local file? Shouldn't it be **`require('plyr')`** instead of `require('./plyr.js')`.

Also, why are you using `plyr` with a lower-case 'p' when the module exports the library as `Plyr`, with an upper-case 'P' in global binding, i.e., binding on `window`.

Your code:

```
plyr.setup('#blast', {
    ...
});
```

The plyr module:

```
! function (e, t) {
    "object" == typeof exports && "undefined" != typeof module
        ? module.exports = t() // commonjs
        : "function" == typeof define && define.amd
            ? define("Plyr", t) // requirejs
            : e.Plyr = t() // window/global binding
}(this, function () {
    ...
});
```

Full dump [here](https://pastebin.com/NXwMzcuQ) and [here](https://github.com/sampotts/plyr/blob/v3.0.0-beta.12/dist/plyr.js). Source [here](https://github.com/sampotts/plyr/blob/v3.0.0-beta.12/src/js/plyr.js#L1214).

You can make it *work* by loading `plyr.js` in your `index.html` before loading your code and use the globally bound `Plyr`.

```
// index.html
<html>
<head>
    <script src="plyr.js"></script> // window.Plyr = ...
</head>
<body>
    ...
    <script src="bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>


//main.js
...
Plyr.setup('#blast', {
    hideControls: true,
    clickToPlay: false,
    controls: []
});
```

You could also import `plyr` module in your code as a **named import**:

```
import Plyr from 'plyr';

...

Plyr.setup('#blast', {
    hideControls: true,
    clickToPlay: false,
    controls: []
});
```

If all this still don't work, I believe it'd best if you share your project code - at least something more than you did alreday.